# Xamarin Froms Android phone camera not opening

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I create xamarin forms where it takes a photo from camera but when i click camera open button it not open the camera. My code is here "https://github.com/Malith1994124/Kiosk/blob/master/Kiosk_V2/Kiosk_V2/Helpers/Utilities.cs" and i gave all required permissions in android section.

Can someone please help me. I am new to xamarin and um stuck here more than 1 week now.

Comment: why are you using await with CrossMedia.Current.Initialize()  i think this could be the problem try removing await

Comment: still not working @RonakShethia

Comment: debug you code and check for the error message

Comment: @RonakShethia no errors, problem is when i click camera open button it not opening and no exception errors receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: set `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);` on your `MainActivity.cs` OnCreate Method.

The CurrentActivity Plugin is a dependency for CrossMedia Plugin and if it didn't create a MainApplication.cs file, you must configure it yourself, and at the minimum, you need that method call.

Comment: Not working, No errors but camera / storage not openning

Comment: Quick question: does the permissions dialog shows up when you try to open the camera/storage for the first time?

Comment: Can you show how are you making the call for camera/storage?

Comment: https://github.com/Malith1994124/Kiosk/blob/master/Kiosk_V2/Kiosk_V2/Helpers/Utilities.cs

Comment: From what I could see, you're mixing the ContinueWith and the Await approach, on the other hand, you're "killing" the exception just catching it but not doing anything with its info. Try setting a logger to see if any exception is thrown and use await or continue with, not both (just a suggestion).